# Asynchronous PHP page loading within javascript tags

Tags: javascript, php, asynchronous

I have the following  tag which loads a PHP and I need it to be loaded asynchronously thus everything in the containing page is load even if the called PHP file takes longer to return the value (or even is server is down).

```
<script language="JavaScript" 
src="http://www.server.com/phpfile.php">
</script>
```

I've tried replacing it with the code use by FB and other methods for JS asynchronous loading but it does not work. The issue is that in this case it is a PHP file the one that is called, not a JS file.

I tried the following but it does not work when the called PHP script plugs HTML code (such as a div with an image) with document.write:

```
<script language="JavaScript"> 
(function () { 
var s = document.createElement('script'); 
s.type = 'text/javascript'; 
s.async = true; s.src = 'server.com/phpfile.php'; 
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x); 
})(); 
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Is the script being loaded, just slowly? or is the script not working?

Comment: There are times in which the script is slowly due to server performance and I need to have the containing site loaded smoothly. There also times (fewer, though) in which the site might be down for maintenance and still need the containing site load without delay.